# SQL Server 2008 Web edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My company is planning to migrate it's intranet/internet based ERP to the latest form of MS SQL Database available. 
Presently we are using SQL Server 2000 Professional.
And we are planning to shift to SQL Server 2008 Web edition.

Please tell me whether this is the right step and whether it is feasible or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sure it's feasible - from a database point of view. Without telling us **what** ERP it is, there's no way of knowing whether that will work or not - most likely, it will. Also: the most recent version of SQL Server is 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Please tell me whether this is the right step " - that's something you and your company need to decide.

It is feasible, and in the majority of cases straight forward.

Your first step should be to run the [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f5a6c5e9-4cd9-4e42-a21c-7291e7f0f852&displaylang=en)

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f5a6c5e9-4cd9-4e42-a21c-7291e7f0f852&displaylang=en) contains the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 **R2** Upgrade Advisor

- **Formulate and test a rollback plan**
- **Determine your upgrade window and acceptable downtime.**
- **Ensure database consistency**: Run DBCC CHECKDB on databases to be upgraded to ensure that they are in a consistent state ***before*** performing the upgrade.
- **Back up all important files:** Back up all SQL Server databases from the instance to be upgraded (including master, model and msdb), data and transaction log files, as well as any application files, script files, extract files, etc. so that you can completely restore them in the event of a failure.

Answer (score 0):

It's both feasible and easy. The path from one version of SQL Server to another is *usually* pretty simple. Do you have any special stored procedures or reports generated in SQL Server that need to be rewritten/re-imported?

As far as right step - the question is, Why? If it's working, do you really need to mess with it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for intranet (some app for your internal usage) then consider using SQL 2008 Express edition. It's free and you can use it as an instance running along the full 2000 version. That way you will have some extra features from the full version.

But you have to know that applications running on SQL 2000 may not work on 2008 and they are even more probable not to work on 2008 R2.